# Regex with Sting Query Issue

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've tried the following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^slides=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z\-0-9_]+)/.*$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

for URLS like
`http://example.com/whatever-in-here/?slides=asdf` to be redirected to `http://example.com/whatever-in-here/?`

However it isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To strip off query string you can add `?` in target:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^slides=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [NE,R=301,L]
```

Also note you don't need to group and capture URI in `RewriteRule` as you can use `%{REQUEST_URI}`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z\-0-9_\.\/]+\/\?).*$ /$1/
```

which will drop everything in the match following the `?`. [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cD0tR6/)